# Sql trigger to add custome invoice number on insert

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Currently I have many records in One table. Now i have added one column Invoice number and i want to write a sql trigger so that if new record is inserted in that table then trigger should add invoice number for ex. P0001, P0002 and so on. but the condition is it should add invoice number after 31st of march mid night. I have already data in my table so I can not use it's automatic incremented Id to append to "P000"+Id as it should start with P0001 and so on. is there any way to do this by trigger or I have to do that in code ?

Comment: The auto-incremented number at the end of the invoice number, does it come from the value in another column (ID field in the table) or is it independent of any other column? Also, will 'P000' remain same for all records or does it also have any logic or dependency on other fields?

Comment: auto incremented number with start from 1 for ex: 'P000'+1,'P000'+2 and so on no dependancy on any other column. and yes 'P000' have some logic of record type of type is 2 then it should be 'W000'

Comment: You can do this through trigger as long as you have a way to _quickly_ identify the next Invoice Number. If you'll use the Invoice Number itself to derive the next in the list, then you'll see poor trigger performance (in that case you'll have to strip the number at the end of the string to calculate the next number to use).

Comment: The [tag:sql] tag is for the SQL Standard. Unfortunately, triggers are a place where different database systems work differently. Please [edit] your question and add an appropriate tag for *which* database system you're using.

Comment: as I have mentioned i am using Sql database. I don't think i should change the tag !

Comment: @Mahesh Which SQL Database? MySQL? MSSQL? ORACLE? PostgresSQL?

Comment: [tag:sql] is for *standard* SQL. [tag:sql-server] would be for SQL Server. Based on previous questions, we might guess what product you're using, but we shouldn't have to. I'd note that this isn't the first time you've posted an SQL question and had people have to chase you up to get an appropriate tag added. Please *learn* from the experience also.

Comment: @SreekanthGS: MSSql database